# LibGDX coordinates after resizing

Tags: java, libgdx, coordinates, viewport

I have an actor on the screen, with a `DragListener` to move him around the stage, and a `ClickListener`. After a click on it i want to draw a rectangle around him (using `ShapeRenderer`), the important thing is that the rectangle position is updating after moving the actor. Works good, until I resize the window (I'm using `ExtendViewport`). The rectangle is not at the correct position (I'm taking the coordinates using Actor's `getX()` and `getY()` methods). Tried the Viewport's `toScreenCoordinates()` method but still it is not correct. Any help with this problem would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you forgetting to update the projection matrix of your `ShapeRenderer` after resize? Something like this:

```
viewport.update();
shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(viewport.getCamera().combined);
```

Comment: Yeah... thought that the solution is simple. Thank you very much.